# Excel ComboBox Scrolling with Mouse

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to work with peter Peter Thornton code which enable the option to scroll with the mouse in a combobox and listbox, an option that isn't built in excel, it works amazing for userforms Comboxes and listboxes but I can't seem to understand how to make this code work for a regular ComboBox on a worksheet

Module Code:

```
'Enables mouse wheel scrolling in controls
Option Explicit

    #If Win64 Then
        Private Type POINTAPI
            XY As LongLong
        End Type
    #Else 
        Private Type POINTAPI
            X As Long
            Y As Long
        End Type
    #End If

    Private Type MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT
        Pt As POINTAPI
        hWnd As Long
        wHitTestCode As Long
        dwExtraInfo As Long
    End Type

    #If VBA7 Then
            Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" _
                Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
                ByVal lpClassName As String, _
                ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long ' not sure if this should be LongPtr

        #If Win64 Then
            Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" _
                Alias "GetWindowLongPtrA" ( _
                ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _
                ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr
        #Else 
            Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" _
                Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
                ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _
                ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr
        #End If

        Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" _
            Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" ( _
            ByVal idHook As Long, _
            ByVal lpfn As LongPtr, _
            ByVal hmod As LongPtr, _
            ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As LongPtr

        Private Declare PtrSafe Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" ( _
            ByVal hHook As LongPtr, _
            ByVal nCode As Long, _
            ByVal wParam As LongPtr, _
            lParam As Any) As LongPtr

        Private Declare PtrSafe Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" ( _
ByVal hHook As LongPtr) As LongPtr ' MAYBE Long
            'Private Declare PtrSafe Function PostMessage Lib "user32.dll" _
            ' Alias "PostMessageA" ( _
            ' ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
            ' ByVal wMsg As Long, _
            ' ByVal wParam As LongPtr, _
            ' ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr ' MAYBE Long

        #If Win64 Then
            Private Declare PtrSafe Function WindowFromPoint Lib "user32" ( _
            ByVal Point As LongLong) As LongPtr '
        #Else 
            Private Declare PtrSafe Function WindowFromPoint Lib "user32" ( _
            ByVal xPoint As Long, _
            ByVal yPoint As Long) As LongPtr '
        #End If

        Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" ( _
            ByRef lpPoint As POINTAPI) As LongPtr 'MAYBE Long
    #Else 
        Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" _
            Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
            ByVal lpClassName As String, _
            ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

        Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32.dll" _
            Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
            ByVal hWnd As Long, _
            ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

        Private Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" _
            Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" ( _
            ByVal idHook As Long, _
            ByVal lpfn As Long, _
            ByVal hmod As Long, _
            ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long

        Private Declare Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" ( _
            ByVal hHook As Long, _
            ByVal nCode As Long, _
            ByVal wParam As Long, _
            lParam As Any) As Long

        Private Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" ( _
ByVal hHook As Long) As Long
            'Private Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32.dll" _
            ' Alias "PostMessageA" ( _
            ' ByVal hwnd As Long, _
            ' ByVal wMsg As Long, _
            ' ByVal wParam As Long, _
            ' ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

        Private Declare Function WindowFromPoint Lib "user32" ( _
            ByVal xPoint As Long, _
            ByVal yPoint As Long) As Long

        Private Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32.dll" ( _
ByRef lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
    #End If

    Private Const WH_MOUSE_LL As Long = 14
    Private Const WM_MOUSEWHEEL As Long = &H20A
    Private Const HC_ACTION As Long = 0
    Private Const GWL_HINSTANCE As Long = (-6)
    'Private Const WM_KEYDOWN As Long = &H100
    'Private Const WM_KEYUP As Long = &H101
    'Private Const VK_UP As Long = &H26
    'Private Const VK_DOWN As Long = &H28
    'Private Const WM_LBUTTONDOWN As Long = &H201
    Dim n As Long
    Private mCtl As Object
    Private mbHook As Boolean

    #If VBA7 Then
        Private mLngMouseHook As LongPtr
        Private mListBoxHwnd As LongPtr
    #Else 
        Private mLngMouseHook As Long
        Private mListBoxHwnd As Long
    #End If

    Sub HookListBoxScroll(frm As Object, ctl As Object)
        Dim tPT As POINTAPI
        #If VBA7 Then
            Dim lngAppInst As LongPtr
            Dim hwndUnderCursor As LongPtr
        #Else 
            Dim lngAppInst As Long
            Dim hwndUnderCursor As Long
        #End If

        GetCursorPos tPT
        #If Win64 Then
            hwndUnderCursor = WindowFromPoint(tPT.XY)
        #Else 
            hwndUnderCursor = WindowFromPoint(tPT.X, tPT.Y)
        #End If

        If TypeOf ctl Is UserForm Then
            If Not frm Is ctl Then
                ctl.SetFocus
            End If
        Else
            If Not frm.ActiveControl Is ctl Then
                ctl.SetFocus
            End If
        End If

        If mListBoxHwnd <> hwndUnderCursor Then
            UnhookListBoxScroll
            Set mCtl = ctl
            mListBoxHwnd = hwndUnderCursor
            #If Win64 Then
                lngAppInst = GetWindowLongPtr(mListBoxHwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE)
            #Else 
                lngAppInst = GetWindowLong(mListBoxHwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE)
            #End If
            ' PostMessage mListBoxHwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0&, 0&
            If Not mbHook Then
                mLngMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx( _
                    WH_MOUSE_LL, AddressOf MouseProc, lngAppInst, 0)
                mbHook = mLngMouseHook <> 0
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub UnhookListBoxScroll()
        If mbHook Then
            Set mCtl = Nothing
            UnhookWindowsHookEx mLngMouseHook
            mLngMouseHook = 0
            mListBoxHwnd = 0
            mbHook = False
        End If
    End Sub

    #If VBA7 Then
        Private Function MouseProc( _
            ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, _
            ByRef lParam As MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT) As LongPtr
        Dim idx As Long
        On Error GoTo errH
        If (nCode = HC_ACTION) Then
            #If Win64 Then
                If WindowFromPoint(lParam.Pt.XY) = mListBoxHwnd Then
                    If wParam = WM_MOUSEWHEEL Then
                        MouseProc = True
                        ' If lParam.hWnd > 0 Then
                        ' postMessage mListBoxHwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_UP, 0
                        ' Else
                        ' postMessage mListBoxHwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_DOWN, 0
                        ' End If
                        ' postMessage mListBoxHwnd, WM_KEYUP, VK_UP, 0
                        If TypeOf mCtl Is Frame Then
                            If lParam.hWnd > 0 Then idx = -10 Else idx = 10
                                idx = idx + mCtl.ScrollTop
                                    If idx >= 0 And idx < ((mCtl.ScrollHeight - mCtl.Height) + 17.25) Then
                                        mCtl.ScrollTop = idx
                            End If
                        ElseIf TypeOf mCtl Is UserForm Then
                            If lParam.hWnd > 0 Then idx = -10 Else idx = 10
                                idx = idx + mCtl.ScrollTop
                                If idx >= 0 And idx < ((mCtl.ScrollHeight - mCtl.Height) + 17.25) Then
                                    mCtl.ScrollTop = idx
                                End If
                            Else
                                If lParam.hWnd > 0 Then idx = -1 Else idx = 1
                                    idx = idx + mCtl.ListIndex
                                    If idx >= 0 And idx <= mCtl.ListCount - 1 Then 
                                        mCtl.ListIndex = idx
                                    End If
                                    Exit Function
                                End If
                            Else
                                UnhookListBoxScroll
                            End If
                        #Else 
                        If WindowFromPoint(lParam.Pt.X, lParam.Pt.Y) = mListBoxHwnd Then
                            If wParam = WM_MOUSEWHEEL Then
                                MouseProc = True
                                ' If lParam.hWnd > 0 Then
                                ' postMessage mListBoxHwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_UP, 0
                                ' Else
                                ' postMessage mListBoxHwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_DOWN, 0
                                ' End If
                                ' postMessage mListBoxHwnd, WM_KEYUP, VK_UP, 0
                                If TypeOf mCtl Is Frame Then
                                    If lParam.hWnd > 0 Then idx = -10 Else idx = 10
                                        idx = idx + mCtl.ScrollTop
                                        If idx >= 0 And idx < ((mCtl.ScrollHeight - mCtl.Height) + 17.25) Then
                                            mCtl.ScrollTop = idx
                                        End If
                                ElseIf TypeOf mCtl Is UserForm Then
                                    If lParam.hWnd > 0 Then idx = -10                 
                                Else 
                                    idx = 10
                                    idx = idx + mCtl.ScrollTop
                                    If idx >= 0 And idx < ((mCtl.ScrollHeight - mCtl.Height) + 17.25) Then
                                        mCtl.ScrollTop = idx
                                    End If
                                Else
                                    If lParam.hWnd > 0 Then idx = -1 Else idx = 1
                                        idx = idx + mCtl.ListIndex
                                            If idx >= 0 And idx <= mCtl.ListCount - 1 Then 
                                                mCtl.ListIndex = idx
                                            End If
                                            Exit Function
                                    End If
                                Else
                                    UnhookListBoxScroll
                                End If
                            #End If
                        End If
                        MouseProc = CallNextHookEx( _
mLngMouseHook, nCode, wParam, ByVal lParam)
                        Exit Function
                        errH:
                            UnhookListBoxScroll
                            End Function
                    #Else 
                        Private Function MouseProc( _
                            ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, _
ByRef lParam As MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT) As Long
                            Dim idx As Long
                            On Error GoTo errH
                            If (nCode = HC_ACTION) Then
                                If WindowFromPoint(lParam.Pt.X, lParam.Pt.Y) = mListBoxHwnd Then
                                    If wParam = WM_MOUSEWHEEL Then
                                        MouseProc = True
                                        ' If lParam.hWnd > 0 Then
                                        ' postMessage mListBoxHwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_UP, 0
                                        ' Else
                                        ' postMessage mListBoxHwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_DOWN, 0
                                        ' End If
                                        ' postMessage mListBoxHwnd, WM_KEYUP, VK_UP, 0

                                        If TypeOf mCtl Is Frame Then
                                            If lParam.hWnd > 0 Then idx = -10 Else idx = 10
                                                idx = idx + mCtl.ScrollTop
                                                If idx >= 0 And idx < ((mCtl.ScrollHeight - mCtl.Height) + 17.25) Then
                                                    mCtl.ScrollTop = idx
                                                End If
                                            ElseIf TypeOf mCtl Is UserForm Then
                                        If lParam.hWnd > 0 Then 
                                            idx = -10                 
                                        Else 
                                            idx = 10
                                            idx = idx + mCtl.ScrollTop
                                            If idx >= 0 And idx < ((mCtl.ScrollHeight - mCtl.Height) + 17.25) Then
                                                mCtl.ScrollTop = idx
                                            End If
                                        Else
                                            If lParam.hWnd > 0 Then idx = -1 Else idx = 1
                                                idx = idx + mCtl.ListIndex
                                            If idx >= 0 And idx <= mCtl.ListCount - 1 Then 
                                                mCtl.ListIndex = idx
                                            End If
                                            Exit Function
                                        End If
                                    Else
                                        UnhookListBoxScroll
                                    End If
                                End If
                                    MouseProc = CallNextHookEx( _
                                        mLngMouseHook, nCode, wParam, ByVal lParam)
                                    Exit Function
                                    errH:
                                        UnhookListBoxScroll
                                        End Function
                                #End If
```

current userform code:

```
Private Sub cmbMyList_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
HookListBoxScroll Me, Me.cmbMyList
End Sub

Private Sub lbxMyList_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
HookListBoxScroll Me, Me.lbxMyList
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
UnhookListBoxScroll
End Sub
```

Current ComboBox code:

```
    Private Sub ComboBox1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Read how to ask a minimal, verifaible & complete question and ask again - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: "how to make this code work for a regular ComboBox on a worksheet"

Comment: @Vityata magic-link: `[mcve]` renders as [mcve] ;-)

Comment: you really need to indent your code properly. it is just a big mess when you look at it .... next to impossible to see how the execution flows. you have not answered what you are trying to do. saying that you are trying to make the code work, does not explain what you are trying to do.  ... in other words, what does the code do when it works correctly

Comment: it makes the combox scroll with the mouse, it works for userforms but i dont understand what need's to be done to make it work on a normal worksheet because im not in this level of coding and this piece is just out of my league

Comment: done a little editing, hope it makes the question clearer

Comment: Alternative solution: [VBA UserForm MouseScroll](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-UserForm-MouseScroll)

Answer (score 7):

Solved, by Jaafar Tribak

the code i use currently (place it in any module):

```
     Option Explicit

Type POINTAPI
    X As Long
    Y As Long
End Type

Type MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
    pt As POINTAPI
    mouseData As Long
    flags As Long
    time As Long
    dwExtraInfo As Long
End Type

#If VBA7 Then
    #If Win64 Then
        Declare PtrSafe Function WindowFromPoint Lib "user32" (ByVal Point As LongLong) As LongPtr
    #Else
        Declare PtrSafe Function WindowFromPoint Lib "user32" (ByVal xPoint As Long, ByVal yPoint As Long) As LongPtr
    #End If
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetParent Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr)
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByRef lpPoint As POINTAPI) As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Function SetFocus Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Function IsWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal idHook As Long, ByVal lpfn As LongPtr, ByVal hmod As LongPtr, ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As LongPtr, ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Dim hwnd As LongPtr, lMouseHook As LongPtr
#Else
    Declare Function WindowFromPoint Lib "user32" (ByVal xPoint As Long, ByVal yPoint As Long) As Long
    Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
    Declare Function GetParent Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Declare Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
    Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
    Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByRef lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
    Declare Function SetFocus Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Declare Function IsWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal idHook As Long, ByVal lpfn As Long, ByVal hmod As Long, ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long
    Declare Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Long, ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
    Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Long) As Long
    Dim hwnd As Long, lMouseHook As Long
#End If

Const WH_MOUSE_LL = 14
Const WM_MOUSEWHEEL = &H20A
Const HC_ACTION = 0

Dim oComboBox As Object

Sub SetComboBoxHook(ByVal Control As Object)
    Dim tPt As POINTAPI
    Dim sBuffer As String
    Dim lRet As Long

    Set oComboBox = Control
    RemoveComboBoxHook
    GetCursorPos tPt
    #If Win64 Then
        Dim lPt As LongPtr
        CopyMemory lPt, tPt, LenB(tPt)
        hwnd = WindowFromPoint(lPt)
    #Else
        hwnd = WindowFromPoint(tPt.X, tPt.Y)
    #End If
    sBuffer = Space(256)
    lRet = GetClassName(GetParent(hwnd), sBuffer, 256)
    If InStr(Left(sBuffer, lRet), "MdcPopup") Then
        SetFocus hwnd
        #If Win64 Then
            lMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, AddressOf MouseProc, Application.HinstancePtr, 0)
        #Else
            lMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, AddressOf MouseProc, Application.Hinstance, 0)
        #End If
    End If
End Sub

Sub RemoveComboBoxHook()
    UnhookWindowsHookEx lMouseHook
End Sub

#If VBA7 Then
    Function MouseProc(ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As MSLLHOOKSTRUCT) As LongPtr
#Else
    Function MouseProc(ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As MSLLHOOKSTRUCT) As Long
#End If

    Dim sBuffer As String
    Dim lRet As Long

    sBuffer = Space(256)
    lRet = GetClassName(GetActiveWindow, sBuffer, 256)
    If Left(sBuffer, lRet) = "wndclass_desked_gsk" Then Call RemoveComboBoxHook
    If IsWindow(hwnd) = 0 Then Call RemoveComboBoxHook

    If (nCode = HC_ACTION) Then
        If wParam = WM_MOUSEWHEEL Then
        #If Win64 Then
            Dim lPt As LongPtr
            CopyMemory lPt, lParam.pt, LenB(lParam.pt)
            If WindowFromPoint(lPt) = hwnd Then
        #Else
            If WindowFromPoint(lParam.pt.X, lParam.pt.Y) = hwnd Then
        #End If
                On Error Resume Next
                    If lParam.mouseData > 0 Then
                        oComboBox.TopIndex = oComboBox.TopIndex - 1 '<---u can change this to change the scrolling speed upwards
                        'u can change "TopIndex" to "listIndex" if you want to change the value instead of hovering it, do not use the dynamic listFillrange if u do!
                    Else
                        oComboBox.TopIndex = oComboBox.TopIndex + 2  '<---u can change this to change the scrolling speed downwards
                        'u can change "TopIndex" to "listIndex" if you want to change the value instead of hovering it, do not use the dynamic listFillrange if u do!
                    End If
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        End If
    End If

    MouseProc = CallNextHookEx(lMouseHook, nCode, wParam, ByVal lParam)
End Function
```

the combobox code (view code to the combobox):

```
 Option Explicit


    'optional
    Dim ComboBoxRange As Range
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim NumRows
    'optional

    Private Sub ComboBox1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
        Call SetComboBoxHook(ComboBox1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_LostFocus()
        Call RemoveComboBoxHook
    End Sub

    'optional, this code is for a dynamic list, do not use if u changed TopIndex to ListIndex!
    'importent note...u need a dynamic list to begin with if u want to use it!
    Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Set myRange = Range("Q:Q")    'the range of data
    NumRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(myRange)
    '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Set ComboBoxRange = Range(Cells(4, 17), Cells(3 + NumRows, 17))
    'my data starts at range Q4, Q = 17, A=1, change this according to the range you want to change
    '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ComboBox1.ListFillRange = ComboBoxRange.Cells.Address
    ComboBox1.DropDown
    End Sub
    'optional
```

Comment: The LostFocus event does not occur after just a MouseMove, and if GotFocus happens, that doesn't cause LostFocus if the mouse moves off that control - a click elsewhere must happen.